# I need transfer data , for example in main page to another page, and see result

Tags: reactjs

I need transfer data , for example in main page to another page, and see result. The data are as follows:

`stop = {
    stop: {
      type: "Pickups",
      name: 'Some Name',
      phone: '(818) 444-6667',
      address: 'ad 1',
      zip: '11111',
      city: "123",
      state: 'CA',
      data:"March 27th",
      time: "11:00pm",
      comments: 'Some comments'
    }
  }`

And for example I want get `stop.type` in  another page like this: `console.log(stop.type)`

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: you need to use props. Google how to pass props to pass data.

Comment: What you are asking here is a very basic operation. [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use history state if you use `react-router-dom`

```
this.props.history.push('/page', {
  stop
})
```

And check data in '/page'

```
console.log(this.props.history.location.state.stop)
```

Comment: Thanks. Use this code in that file , in which i want see the result?

Comment: I try it , but I didn't use react-router-dom

Comment: If you don't use `react-router-dom` check this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method But this isn't good way in SPA. Other way, you can get the data by using `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so but not exactly like the way you did , You can do as follow

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stop = {
        stop: {
          type: "Pickups",
          name: 'Some Name',
          phone: '(818) 444-6667',
          address: 'ad 1',
          zip: '11111',
          city: "123",
          state: 'CA',
          data:"March 27th",
          time: "11:00pm",
          comments: 'Some comments'
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

have this in your constructor and in you can pass to the other components via two ways using the history props or importing the second component in the first component and pass the values

> 1.via history props

```
 this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/your component url as specified in route' }, { 
          stop: this.state.stop.stop}})
```

you can access the value stop using `this.props.location && this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.stop`

> 2.importing the component

```
import Yourcomponent from './yourcomponent '; /*This has to done in your parent component*/

render(){
return(<Yourcomponent stop={this.state.stop.stop}/>)}
```

you can access via this.props.stop

Comment: ./src/pages/loads/new-load-popup/AddStopPopup.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (56:10)
``` super(props);
    this.state = {
    stop = {
       ^
    stop: {
    type: "kkkkkkkk",
   name: 'Some Name'```

Comment: it should work can you provide more code I coudn't find exact issue